# Parsing through form with unknown number of fields

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm working on an invite system where a user can invite one or more people to be coordinators for their account. To allow the user to invite more than one person at a time I'm using mootools to create another row of fields whenever the user clicks a plus. In my example below I'll be using just two rows but they could invite much more if they'd like.

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Email Address</td>
            <td>Invites</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="coords">
        <tr id="row-1">
            <td id="1-1"><input type="text" name="fname-1"></td>
            <td id="1-2"><input type="text" name="lname-1"></td>
            <td id="1-3"><input type="text" name="email-1"></td>
            <td id="1-4"><input type="text" name="invites-1"></td>
            <td id="1-5"><span id="minus-1" class="minus">( - )</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-2">
            <td id="2-1"><input type="text" name="fname-2"></td>
            <td id="2-2"><input type="text" name="lname-2"></td>
            <td id="2-3"><input type="text" name="email-2"></td>
            <td id="2-4"><input type="text" name="invites-2"></td>
            <td id="2-5"><span id="plus-2" class="plus">( + )</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

$_POST looks like this

```
Array
(
    [fname-1] => David
    [lname-1] => Last
    [email-1] => email address
    [invites-1] => 15
    [fname-2] => Shirley
    [lname-2] => Last
    [email-2] => other email
    [invites-2] => 10
    [action] => invite
)
```

PHP parsing is this

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $_SESSION['inviteCoordinators'] = $_POST;
    $newCoordinators = array();


    //loop through all fields
    while(list($key,$value) = each($_SESSION['inviteCoordinators'])) {
        if($key != 'action') {
            list($field, $user) = explode("-",$key);
            $newCoordinators[$user] = array (
                $field => $value
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting $newCoordinators to look like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
           (
               [fname] => David
               [lname] => Last
               [email] => email address
               [invites => 15
           )
    [2] => Array
           (
               [fname] => Shirley
               [lname] => Last
               [email] => other email
               [invites => 10
           )
```

But all that I'm getting is the [1][invites] => 15 and [2][invites] => 10. I assume i'm only seeing the invites because the others are getting overwritten but I can't make sense of why that would be. What's wrong with my parsing? Or, how should I be doing it?

Side note, the only required field will be the email address.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: use name="fname[]", name="lname[]", name="email[]" etc. this way it will create the array you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just name your html form elements using arrays? You could make the form something like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Email Address</td>
            <td>Invites</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="coords">
        <tr id="row-1">
            <td id="1-1"><input type="text" name="invites[1][fname]"></td>
            <td id="1-2"><input type="text" name="invites[1][lname]"></td>
            <td id="1-3"><input type="text" name="invites[1][email]"></td>
            <td id="1-4"><input type="text" name="invites[1][invites]"></td>
            <td id="1-5"><span id="minus-1" class="minus">( - )</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-2">
            <td id="1-1"><input type="text" name="invites[2][fname]"></td>
            <td id="1-2"><input type="text" name="invites[2][lname]"></td>
            <td id="1-3"><input type="text" name="invites[2][email]"></td>
            <td id="1-4"><input type="text" name="invites[2][invites]"></td>
            <td id="2-5"><span id="plus-2" class="plus">( + )</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and you would get your post data already formatted like:

```
Array
(
    [invites] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fname] => first1
                    [lname] => last1
                    [email] => test@test.com
                    [invites] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fname] => first2
                    [lname] => last2
                    [email] => test2@test.com
                    [invites] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Then you could just do something like:

```
foreach($_POST['invites'] as $invite){
    //process invite
    echo "{$invite['fname']} {$invite['lname']} was invited. <br />";
}
```

Comment: You can just use fname[] instead of invites[1][fname]. Makes it easier to dynamically add fields.

Comment: @Grumpy `fname[]` wouldn't produce the same output. Also, you would have to assume that `fname[0]` corresponds to `lname[0]` which isn't that bad, but if there are any checkboxes named `checkbox[]` for example, only the checkboxes that are checked are submitted so you can't assume that `checkbox[0]` corresponds to `fname[0]`. `checkbox[0]` would be the first checkbox checked which might have been next to `fname[1]`. I just prefer to be verbose in numbering to make sure there are no mistakes.

Comment: @ Jonathan You are right in general, but for this case name[] is more useful, if  plus is clicked 4 more inputfields will show.

Comment: @Grumpy, is it really that hard to rename an input field to correspond to a count number? I just think it is easier to do use the looping code in my example than doing something like: `for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['fname']);$i++){echo "{$_POST['fname'][$i]} {$_POST['lname'][$i]} was invited <br />";}`

Comment: @ Jonathan first the plus button is handled in java, adding name[] is easier, no need of keeping track of a counter. In php i would use for each, this will make the reading of the post array easier.

Comment: @Grumpy your method wouldn't make a foreach loop any easier, perhaps `foreach($_POST['fname'] as $key=>$fname){ echo "{$_POST['fname'][$key]} {$_POST['lname'][$key]} was invited.<br />";}`, once again assuming that the fname[N] and lname[N] correspond, but that is still not as easy as the method I used IMO. Especially considering it produces the exact output he requested with no extra parsing in php. And the javaSCRIPT, is it really that hard to have a counter++?

Comment: Seems brilliant. Trying now. Will check mark if it's a success. Will ask questions if I've still got issues. THANKS!